# How to Close Windows in Mission Control of El Capitan?

Tags: macos, mission-control

This feature was previously under ALT when X symbols appeared to windows corners. Now, I see that it has been removed in El Capitan.

My settings in Mission control

[image]

---

How can you have close-window symbols in Mission Control of El Capitan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first trigger Mission Control you now get Desktop names rather than icons of desktops

[image]

...which seems to be one pointless additional step, to me... however...

Once you hover over the names, they turn to icons.

[image]

Wait half a second longer & an X appears in the corner of the one your cursor is over .

[image]

At that point, holding  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  will show X's over them all.

[image]

After comments - a picture of my Mission Control settings, in case they make a difference to functionality...

[image]

Comment: It does not show for me. Any video or more clearer what you do?

Comment: I'm doing nothing more than what I said above. I'll post a pic of my Mission Control settings, see if that may make the difference - perhaps 'Displays have separate Spaces' as that one really changes the behaviour.

Comment: I set my Mission Control's settings same as you but still the same result. No X symbol coming visible.

Comment: Then I'd test it in a fresh account, see if it's something you have installed on that account that makes the difference.

Comment: @Tetsujin from your screenshots in response, it seems like you are talking about 'X' on corners of space icons i.e. 'Desktop 1', 'Desktop 2' etc, but OP was asking about 'X' on window icon corners, that is application windows  in mission control view.

Comment: You may be right. However, the OP never returned to provide further explanation/comment, other than what you see above. [Edit... Except for right now marking it as the accepted answer ;)