# How to close apps from Mission Control on macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, mission-control

I'm used to being able to close my apps from the mission control view by clicking on an X sign in the upper left corner - I don't have this feature in Sierra. How can I turn it back on or do it in a similar way from Mission Control?

Comment: You said, "X sign in the upper left corner", where exactly is this and what OS were you running that you saw this in Mission Control? I'm asking because I do not see that on any window when in Mission Control in OS X 10.11.6. Nor can I click anything to close a window when in Mission Control, even if when using standard modifier keys. Now in a normal Desktop view if I mouse-over the red close button it changes from solid red to a black x on a red circle but it doesn't do this when in Mission Control, when there it stays solid red on only the front most window prior to going to Mission Control.

Comment: [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231154/how-to-close-windows-in-mission-control-of-el-capitan] here's a link to a question that has a graphic representation of it - I had this X sign on El Capitan, except that it was black and on the individual apps, not workspaces.

Comment: The image referenced in the link of your comment is to the virtual Desktops **not** applications and I can close additional virtual Desktops from Mission Control in macOS Sierra just like I can in OS X El Capitan. When I click on the The (x) in the upper left corner of the icon for the virtual Desktop it is closed and the apps on that Desktop are moved to another Desktop in either version of the Mac OS. So it is still unclear what your issue is as you've obviously not described it correctly in your original post.

Comment: I have described it correctly - I want to be able to close apps from Mission Control. Not workspaces, apps. What's wrong with this description? I've had this feature OOTB on El Capitan and I don't have it on Sierra, I want to have it back.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently bought a new MacBook Pro after 4 years of using Windows, and I really missed the ability of directly closing windows in Mission Control, as I used to do in my good old Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

I have searched around the web and in macOS Sierra settings, but I didn't found a OS native way of achieving it.

So I installed this little tool (I also used it in the old days) called [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net). It allows you to set customised keyboard and gesture shortcuts.

I use a 3 finger tap to close windows directly bellow the cursor (which works anywhere, even in Mission Control). You can set up any shortcut you want. I find using it very convenient, I hope you do also.

[image]

Comment: Nice tip!
Anyway it has one caveat/error. It closes app. Not quits.

Comment: Yup, but in previous OSX versions it would also just close the app. I also have a gesture shortcut for quitting, but the app needs to be in focus. In Mission Control it doesn't work.